# CCParticleSystemQuad stop/pause/resume/play ability?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

looking if there is a pause/resume method in this class.
something like :[CCParticleSystemQuad resume];
do I missing ? or not exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not officially. But you could edit the source code, add a BOOL property `paused` and check the paused flag in the update method:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if (_paused == NO)
    {
        // update particles code here...
    }
}
```

No guarantee that it'll work but it's worth giving it a try.

It might also be possible without changing the code, but this will affect other scheduled methods and actions too:

```
[particleSystem pauseSchedulerAndActions];
```

To resume:

```
[particleSystem resumeSchedulerAndActions];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick that I used, was setEmissionRate() function.
To pause particle system:

> setEmissionRate(0);

To resume particle system:

> setEmissionRate(latestValue);

I hope this should be good for you :)